# Problems with Topojson scale

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, scale, topojson

Hi i am having a little issue working on drawing a topojson map.
My topojson file has following properties:

```
{"type":"Topology","arcs":[[[6566,5055] ... 
"transform":{"scale":[0.00014849648332078075,0.00015400850549819297], ...
```

On my script:

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
.scale(5000)
.translate([width/2 , height/2 ])
```

When scale is set at 200, it is very tiny almost invisible; while set at really large scale, it is totally blank. How do I interpret the scale in topojson file and in my script?

Answer (score 0):

The scale factor on a topojson is used is part of ([from API documentation](https://github.com/topojson/topojson/wiki/Introduction)):

> a transform which specifies how to convert delta-encoded integer
>   coordinates to their native values (such as longitude & latitude).

While the scale relates to ([D3 API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#projection_scale)):

> The scale factor corresponds linearly to the distance between
>   projected points; however, absolute scale factors are not equivalent
>   across projections.

I would not consider that one will help you with the other. Especially as different projection types will have different scale values for similar features. This applies even within a single projection, for example Mercator, which will require different scale values to zoom in on different features of the same size depending on where they are - due to distortion like in any projection.

With a D3 Mercator projection, a scale value of 200 can show almost the entire planet (960px x 500 px). So, your features will be small (unless your features are the entire planet). Zooming in with larger scale values will help increase the size of your features relative to the view port.

But, where are you zooming to? By default, a Mercator projection will zoom to [0,0], the intersection of the prime meridian and the equator, off the coast of Africa. Your features are probably not located in this portion of the Atlantic. You need to zoom to a specific area - and this is done by using either or both of the `.center()` and `.rotate()` methods of a d3 projection.

You will need to know a point in the middle of your area of interest, it doesn't need to be exact. Then you need to set where your projection will focus. For a Mercator projection, this could look like:

```
.center(x,y)
```

Or (not both):

```
.rotate(-x,-y)
```

where x is the longitude of the center of your area of interest and y is the latitude of the center of your area of interest. You will still need to scale your projection of course. Starting with a small value for your scale parameter and then zooming in will help ensure you are centered in the right area at least.